# Boiling wheat vs barley

Tags: grains

I love both barley (which I eat savory) and wheat (which I eat as sweet power snack). While the two grains look and ultimately feel and taste alike, the cooking processes are quite different. I prepare barley by simply boiling the grain straight out of bag and it takes usually around 20 min. As for wheat, I soak it overnight and the boil more than an hour before it's tender enough to chew.

Why are the cooking processes between these two similar grains so different?

Comment: What kind of barley do you use? Pear barley, whole berries, groats...?

Comment: I dunno. It comes in grains

Comment: What does the package say? Pictures?

Comment: It can't be pearl barley as that takes at least 40 minutes to cook, whole berries is longer.

Comment: @GdD that's what baffeled me, too. But coarse groats or the extra-fine pearl could be cooked in 20 minutes.